# App installer not finding the apk's

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card, installation, apk

I just installed Marshmallow. I have apk files on my SD card and have in the past used Easy Installer to install them. For some reason it doesn't detect any. I tried another apk installer and it couldn't detect any either. I can use File Explorer to manually navigate to the apk folder on the SD card so I know its there. How can I install apk's (easily using an app) on Marshmallow? I remebered to check option "allow installation of apps from unknown sources".

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but: have you checked the permission manager? I have experienced a permission reset after upgrading to Android M for the first time, so you might need to check some apps permission to make sure that they can access the Storage again.

Comment: @AndrewT. how do you change the permissions for the app?

Comment: Go to Settings - Apps - <the app name> - Permissions, then check if there's disabled permission.

Comment: Nope I checked and storage is allowed. However I tried dissalowing it and got the warning say "this app was designed for an older version of android and turning this off may break it" so maybe the app really is just not compatible with M.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file manager then explore the directory of sdcard where the apks are exists then click on it to install and check unknown sources if asked by android , by this you know whether the apks exists and supported by your mobile phone new upgrade.

Then you need to go to application manager select Easy Installer  and check its permissions required to explore sdcard and install apps.
Another important thing is that it may be possible that your apks are old and not supported to marshmallow.

Or you can simply go to application manager then go to Easy Installer clear all app data then restart it.
Then definitely it will ask for all the required permissions.
or you can check for update , the latest version is 3.1.6 , check it that you have the same else update

another thing is that many peoples reporting at google play that this app is not able to find apks now.
here is the url:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.installer&hl=en
read the review carefully

Comment: do you know every android app has target sdk version as well as compile sdk version, if the target sdk version is Lolipop then that app i incompatible with marshmallow

Comment: it seems you  developed the Easy Installer that's why you are presenting too many questions here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44238/discussion-between-umar-ata-and-andy-yan).